# Special Characters in Android Bar

Tags: android, tabs, android-actionbar, android-actionbar-compat

I 'm from Brazil and my English is bad, sorry.

I have updated my app, but now it is showing special characters in the action bar tabs. What can I do to fix this?

[image]

Comment: Show the code snippets, where you are setting the text for tabs.

Comment: Oh, thanks, I rewrite the text for tabs and compile again, worked